# How JavaScript compiling sequence works in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Why placing the Error line of code it at the bottom, runs rest of the program. But placing it here doesn't run any single function, causes the  error.

```
const A = "A";
let F;

function doStuff(B) {
  console.log(B);
  const C = "C";
  let H = "H";
  if (1 + 1 === 2) {
    const D = "D";
    H = "something else";
  }

  console.log(H);
  F = "F";
}

console.log(B); // I know it has error

let E = 0;
while (E < 3) {
  E++;
  console.log(A); //But why this
}
doStuff("B"); // and this
console.log(E); // and this is not working unless I remove that line or place that in the bottom of the code.
```

Comment: *I know it has error*, then fix it as that's the issue

Comment: It sounds like you need to research Javascript **scope**

Answer (score 0):

Variable B is not defined anywhere so of course it will yell at you.

```js
const A = "A";
let F;

function doStuff(B) {
  console.log(B);
  const C = "C";
  let H = "H";
  if (1 + 1 === 2) {
    const D = "D";
    H = "something else";
  }

  console.log(H);
  F = "F";
}

//console.log(B);  <-- What is B, it is not defined anywhere so Javascript will yell at you becasue it doesn't know what it is

let E = 0;
console.log(E); //this works here because E is initialized
while (E < 3) {
  E++;
  console.log(A); //variable A defined at the top of the code can be accessed here so this will work
}
doStuff("B"); // and this
console.log(E); //it will also works here
```

As for why placing console.log(B) at the bottom will run a partial part of the code instead of throwing an error right at the bat like C++ or C#, JavaScript is an interpreted language, not a compiled language. What this means is that when you run a piece of code, there will be an intepreter that will read through each line of code one by one then intepret it. There is no compilation steps at all in Javascript.

For example, this will still output "Hello" as the browser read the first line, interprets it then run it. It doesn't know what is happening at the second line

```js
console.log("Hello");
console.log(A)
```

Comment: I know that B is not defined and compiler thus shows and error without even printing other stuff. But If I place that line in the end of the code it print other stuff and then shows error. Why?

`const A ....

let E = 0;
while (E < 3) {
  E++;
  console.log(A);   //Now it works
}
doStuff("B");      // this also
console.log(E);   // and this
console.log(B);    // As it is in the last `

Why placing it at the bottom, runs the program partially and placing it above doesn't? IS THERE IS A PARTICULAR SEQUENCE OF COMPILATION IN JS

Comment: Did you paste the code into chrome devtool to execute?

Comment: I am running it in VS CODE and few online compilers. If i place the line as i ask in the question `ReferenceError: B is not defined` this is the output. and if i place the line in bottom `A
A
A
B
something else
3
ReferenceError: B is not defined` these are the output. Why it is executing other things and then showing error, rather than showing it all above.